# How do I list missing data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2014, I am working with a table of dates and a few values. This is how the table looks:

```
Date          Number1   Number2   Number3
-----------------------------------------
2018-01-01     34        54        13
2018-01-01     34        53        13
2018-01-01     30        53        13
2018-01-02     27        50        10
2018-01-02     28        51         9
2018-01-02     27        50         9
2018-01-03     29        59         7
2018-01-03     29        60         7
2018-01-03     30        62         7
2018-01-05     36        44        17
2018-01-05     34        44        17
2018-01-05     34        43        18
2018-01-06     31        49        13
2018-01-06     34        47        10
2018-01-06     33        48        12
2018-01-07     30        50        12
2018-01-07     31        49        12
2018-01-07     30        50        12
2018-01-09     31        48        15
2018-01-09     30        48        17
2018-01-09     30        50        17
....           ...       ...       ...
```

The data is loaded every day (multiple rows per day) but sometimes it is not loaded and is missing. I want to get the list of the missing days. In this case, my output would look like this meaning that nothing was loaded that day:

```
Date          
-----------
2018-01-04  
2018-01-08  
...
```

My query:

```
SELECT [Date] 
FROM [dbo].[my_table]
WHERE [Date] = '';
```

but this returns no output. How should I correct it?

Comment: Use a calendar table and a `LEFT JOIN` to your table.

Comment: that query is looking for rows where the date is blank. But if the data wasn't loaded there won't _be_ any rows to search, right? You need to have a list of all possible days and left join that to your data so you can identify days for which there are no rows in your data table.

Answer (score 1):

If, you don't have Calendar table, you should use recursive *`cte`* approach by that generate the maximum loaded date

```
WITH cte as 
(
    SELECT MIN(cast([date] as date)) mindate, MAX(cast([date] as date)) maxdate 
    FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, mindate) mindate, maxdate 
    FROM cte
    WHERE mindate < maxdate 
)
SELECT c.mind FROM cte  c
LEFT JOIN table t ON cast(t.[date] as date) = c.mind
WHERE t.date IS NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I tried doing so getting this error: Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "mindate" of recursive query "cte". 

Worth mentioning that the data type of the column Date is not a date but nvarchar(255) and I can't freely change it.

Comment: @LinaLinutina... ensure that the date value has date type not other else you would need to cast them as `cast([date] as date) mindate`

Comment: @LinaLinutina... storing the date value as varchar/nvarchar is bad at all cause you would often require to cast them as date. check edited.

Comment: Thank you, I indeed casted it as date and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table-valued function that take `Start_Date` & `End_Date` as parameters and returns a table contains all days within `Start_Date` & `End_Date` , then right join this function